# In the Base + Offset addressing, Offset address is also known as

Tags: addressing-mode

In the Base + Offset addressing, Offset address is also known as:

(a) Physical Address

(b) Logical Address

(c) Actual Address

(d) Instruction Address

(e) None of these

Kindly answer it. To me it might be (b) or (d). 
Am I right?

Comment: Logical Address is the most logical answer in this case (though some would call it Virtual Address, but it's kind of the same). Actual Address is just another way of saying Physical Address, and it sure ain't physical address, so that rules out options 'a' and 'c'. Instruction Address - well, personally, I've never heard this terminology, but you could ascribe it to the address of an instruction, typically located in the code-section of the executable image. It has nothing to do with the 'Base+Offset' scheme (i.e., the translation from logical to physical is "one layer below", at the MMU).

Answer (score 0):

Offset address is also known as relative address.
so the right answer is (e)

Answer (score 0):

In this context an offset is sometimes called a relative address. In IBM System/360 instructions, a 12-bit offset embedded within certain instructions provided a range of between 0 and 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

(d) Instruction Address

Base + Offset addressing, Offset address is also known as Instruction Address.

[image]